# Milliseconds to frames jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an animate function, the duration of which I have set to an arbitrary number of 50. I also am animating a variable using the `step` parameter. The code:

```
$('.shadow-right').animate(
                    {
                        opacity: 0
                    },
                    {
                        duration: 50,
                        step: function(){
                            for (var i = 0; i < statsActualPos.length; i++) {
                                statsActualPos[i]-=statsTargetPos[i]/50;
                            }
                        }
                    }, function() {
                        statsIsActive = false;
                    });
```

The problem is I don't know how many frames it is taking to complete this animation. Is there a formula to find the number of frames in a jQuery animation? My frameRate is 40 fps.

Comment: No, the fps can vary through the whole animation. So you cannot determine how many frames the animation will take.

Comment: :( Even if I explicitly set the frameRate in javascript? I'm also using a library called p5.js, and I used this function: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate

Comment: You can calculate a rough guess, but not an exact number. This guess could be off for an arbitrary number depending one the actual browser or system usage. Why do you need to know the number of frames? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: For what I need a rough guess would probably be fine. I'm making an HTML5 game and I'm using this to animate the player's health bar in and out. (Which is why I can't use css animations, since the bar is drawn inside the canvas)

Comment: But why do you need the information about the fps. Why can't you use the start and end value of the animation and its percentage? Or the elapsed time? You should explain what you exactly try to achieve, how the animation of the healthbar should look like.

Comment: Well, I thought I needed the exact number of frames in order to calculate the what percent of the animation was complete, but I wasn't aware that there was a `progress` arg for animate... just realized that. :P Thanks, I might be able to achieve what I want by using the `progress` option. I'll close this question now :P Sorry